# Regex in applyCondition not matching

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using the following code

```
TypedAggregation<LocBean> agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    LocBean.class, 
    match(criteria),
    project(" "locNam", "locSta", "locCnt", "areasCvrd").and("scre")
    //.applyCondition(ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("areasCvrd").is("Alachua County, FL"))
    .applyCondition(ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("areasCvrd").regex("Alachua County, FL"))
    .then(100)
    .otherwise(8))
);
```

`Criteria.where("areasCvrd").is("Alachua County, FL")` works fine. I get rows with score = 100 and 8

If I use regex, which I would like to use because I am searching for substring, it always return 8.  Why the regex is not matching?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below `Criteria`

```
Criteria.where("areasCvrd").regex("Alachua County, FL")
```

with

```
StringOperators.RegexMatch.valueOf("areasCvrd").regex("Alachua County, FL")
```